# Multiple tasks not executing using celery in python flask

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, celery-task

I've 2 files viz. logic.py and app.py In logic file there are various functions and app file is a flask file. in app.py file im writing a few things to set things working for celery so that it schedules the tasks at a particular time interval.
my logic.py looks similar like this:

```
#import statements
class xyz:
    @celery.task(name='scheduler',once={'graceful':True})
    def scheduler(self)
        #rest of the code

    @celery.task(name='scheduler2',once={'graceful':True})
    def scheduler2(self):
        #rest of the code
```

and my app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

app = Flask(__name__)
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

def make_celery(app):
    #Celery configuration
    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
    app.config['CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
    app.config['CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT'] = ['json','yaml','msgpack']
    app.config['CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES'] = 30
    app.config['CELERY_TIMEZONE'] = 'Asia/Calcutta'
    app.config['CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE'] = True
    app.config['CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER'] = 1
    app.config['CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE'] = {
        # Executes every 5 minutes
        'scheduler-every-minute': {
            'task': 'scheduler',
            'schedule': crontab('*/5'),
            'args': ({ },)
        },
        'scheduler2-every-thursday': {
            'task': 'scheduler2',
            'schedule': crontab(day_of_week='Thursday',hour=12,minute=40),
            'args': ({ }, )
        },
    }
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery(app)
```

I'm more concerned as to why upon running celerybeat and worker it executes only one task. I wanted to run both these tasks parallely on my machine however only the first task is getting executed. Can anyone please help me out where I am going wrong?

Comment: its probably your second task is running on Thursday. You can test your second task maybe running every 6 minutes to see if both tasks can run in parallel.

Comment: @DDhaliwal i tried it but only the first task runs and when i try to close it a warm shutdown takes place(which takes a very long time to close the worker,since it makes sure to end the task and then close the worker) so i try to close it again,this time cold shutdown takes place